# How to get the "real" IP addresses of all clients connected to websocket server

Tags: node.js, websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

So I have a [nodejs web socket server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) sitting behind a nginx reverse proxy. My nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass ​http://localhost:9898;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

My web socket server application code contains logic that stores the client's IP address in a table for retrieving later. I don't have a problem retrieving the client's IP address when they connect because I can simply do something like this `req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]` since I have access to the `req` object on every new connection. My problem is retrieving that "forwarded IP address" whenever I want to send out a server broadcast only to a subset of certain clients. Because whenever I do `ws._socket.remoteAddress` (where `ws` is the web socket object), I expectantly get the IP address: `127.0.0.1`.

I guess this is a question regarding the specific npm package I'm using to host a web socket server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is answered in [the NPM page you linked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-client):

> When the server runs behind a proxy like NGINX, the de-facto standard is to use the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

> ```
> wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
>   const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(/\s*,\s*/)[0];
> });
> ```

You could store that `ip` on the `ws` object (and in fact, you can **maybe** overwrite `ws._socket.remoteAddress` with that `ip` too) at that point.

Comment: Yep storing the "real" IP address in a custom property within the `ws` object works perfectly! Can't believe I didn't think of that! Whenever I tried to overwrite the `ws._socket.remoteAddress` property though, it gave me an error indicating `_socket` is a private property. Anyways, thanks!